# Pass Data to Subview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

How can I pass data to a subview?

---

SubviewViewController.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;
```

TableViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Load SubView    
    SubviewViewController *SVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubviewViewController"];

    SVC.lblName.text = @"TEST"; // It's not working properly.

    SVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, SVC.view.frame.size.width, SVC.view.frame.size.height);
    [self addChildViewController: SVC];
    [SVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:SVC.view];
}
```

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by "not properly"?

Comment: below @samfisher answer is correct, also check did you have such line `#import "SubviewViewController.h";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVC.lblName.text = @"TEST";` wont work as the label is not yet initialised. the reason being that the view which is having the label is not loaded into the memory until `[self.view addSubview:SVC.view];` and hence the `lblName` would be `nil`... so how to fix that??

moving this line `SVC.lblName.text = @"TEST";`below `[self.view addSubview:SVC.view];` will fix the issue of property initialisation as when `SCV.view` is added as subview the `lblName` will be assigned the property/outlet..

hope this would work for you if everything else is paired correctly in ur code.